# XCode 4.3 - perl can't find C compiler after upgrade from XCode 4.2

Tags: c, perl, compiler-construction, osx-lion, xcode4.3

I recently upgraded to Lion and to XCode 4.3 and now anything that I do with perl that requires the C compiler is failing to build:

```
root# perl Makefile.PL 
Couldn't find your C compiler
Compilation failed in require at Makefile.PL line 5.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at Makefile.PL line 5.
```

my c compiler is set to:

```
root# perl -V:cc
cc='llvm-gcc-4.2';
```

Is there anything that changed on XCode 4.3?, how do I set the C Compiler for perl now?.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The new version of Xcode doesn't install the binaries (such as the C compiler) where they can be found in your `$PATH`.  You'll need to go to the "Downloads" section of your XCode preferences and elect to install the command line tools.

More information [from Apple](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/WhatsNewXcode/Articles/xcode_4_3.html) (look for "Command line tools are optional").

Answer (score 0):

If you think they're compatible, you could create a symlink or edit Config.pm (path = `perl -MConfig -E'say $INC{"Config.pm"}'`).